# Clean the merge from some features

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a layer of pipes,water conductors, that I merged  under the condition of having the same material and they're touching each other, it did a good work but  some features which  have the same material but not touching each other are also merged. 
the code below shows the query I executed to merge the features :

```
drop table if exists touches_material;
CREATE TABLE touches_material AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
       sub_query.*
FROM (
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT a.id) AS old_id, a.material,
           ST_Union(a.geom) AS fusion
    FROM pipe AS a,
         pipe AS b
    WHERE a.id <> b.id
      AND a.material = b.material
      AND ST_touches(a.geom, b.geom)
    GROUP BY a.material
) AS sub_query
```

So I was thinking about finding a function that clears the merge when the touch is not realized and the pipes have the same material. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257357/features-merging shouldnt you resolve this one first?

Comment: I didn't receive any feedback so that I managed to write an other question. Both are invoking the same issue.

Comment: did the query bekow help you out? or gave it any false results?

Answer (score 2):

Since I just learned about [ST_ClusterIntersecting](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html) from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257613/93656) answer, I'll provide a way better solution than the query above (that I wrote as a solution to [your initial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257196/merge-features-n-time/257211#257211) question...). Try this (don´t forget to fill in `<YOUR_SRID>`):

```
SELECT array_agg(pipe.id) AS old_id,
       cluster.material,
       cluster.geom
FROM (
  SELECT material,
         ST_SetSRID(
           ST_CollectionHomogenize(
             unnest( 
               ST_ClusterIntersecting(
                 pipe.geom
               )
             )
           ),
           <YOUR_SRID>
         ) AS geom
  FROM pipe
  GROUP BY pipe.material
) AS cluster,
  pipe
WHERE ST_Intersects(pipe.geom, cluster.geom)
  AND pipe.material = cluster.material
GROUP BY cluster.material,
         cluster.geom
```