# Calculate id network

Tags: postgis, postgresql, network, geometric-network

In Postgis/Postgres given a set of linestrings with topological connected edges, how can one calculate a unique id (network id) grouped by a set of attributes. 
Installed postgis/pgrouting and looking at possibilities but so far could not find a solution.

Comment: mh...with not questioning your question I'd say _GROUP BY <set_of_attributes>_...? However I suspect there's more to it...could  you specify a little more?

Comment: grouping by road name only  .. all linestrings connected with same name receiving a unique id

Comment: got this to work?

Comment: No success unfortunately, any clue how ?

Comment: ah...I think I have misunderstood your question, you want to keep the linestrings, don´t want them merged...try my updated query below.

Comment: Thanks I will be trying this tomorrow’s and will let you know. Ok

Answer (score 1):

I quite recently found the *ST_Cluster...* family of functions to be the Holy Grail for these kind of tasks, with your task being close to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257595/clean-the-merge-from-some-features/257659#257659) one.

Based on my answer there, something along the lines of this should get you going:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
       cluster.name,
       array_agg(<OLD_ATTRIBUTE_1>) AS attr_1_array,
       array_agg(<OLD_ATTRIBUTE_n>) AS attr_n_array,
       cluster.geom
FROM (
  SELECT name,
         ST_SetSRID(
           ST_CollectionHomogenize(
             unnest( 
               ST_ClusterIntersecting(
                 network.geom
               )
             )
           ),
           <YOUR_SRID>
         ) AS geom
  FROM <YOUR_NETWORK> AS network
  GROUP BY network.name
) AS cluster,
<YOUR_NETWORK> AS network
WHERE ST_Intersects(network.geom, cluster.geom)
  AND network.name = cluster.name
GROUP BY cluster.name,
         cluster.geom
```

(Adapted this out of my head and might need to be reviewed, but this is the general structure)

EDIT:
Late, but I now get that you want your original geometries (each linestring) updated with a unique ID based on same name and connection, not the collected geometries as a multilinestring...this slightly altered one should be the query you were looking for then:

```
SELECT cluster.network_id,
       network.*
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS network_id,
         name,
         ST_SetSRID(
           ST_CollectionHomogenize(
             unnest( 
               ST_ClusterIntersecting(
                 network.geom
               )
             )
           ),
           <YOUR_SRID>
         ) AS geom
  FROM <YOUR_NETWORK> AS network
  GROUP BY network.name
) AS cluster,
<YOUR_NETWORK> AS network
WHERE network.name = cluster.name
  AND ST_Intersects(network.geom, cluster.geom)
```

Late indeed, and I only came back to fuss about not getting any feedback on what I thought to be the right answer...,)

Comment: still in this list of todo's .. did not forget :-) thanks